# Git submodule : automatic merge

Tags: git, git-submodules

Is it possible, with git, to automaticaly make a merge inside a submodule only asking merge inside main module ? Is there a command / option to do that ?

Goal is, in main module, to be on branch1 with submodules on same branch1. When a merge command between branch1 and a remote branch is used within main module, that merge branch1 with remote branch within submodule too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shortly, no.
You need to specify it for the submodules using `git submodule update --remote --merge`.

You can see plenty of explanations on submodules in the official documentation [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

Comment: After reading, I understand that --remote --merge permit to merge local modification with remote modification. Is it correct ? If yes, I have update my OP (not sure that this change your answer)

Comment: That is right. It will update your local changes to the remote (from super-repo to submodule) by merging the two latest commits, and the head is attached to the branch that the submodule is tracking.
See [man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule).

Comment: Thanks, yes I read man, my first comment is a question after reading man. Sometime it is not sufficient to understand. Unfortunately I have some errors when trying this command. I'm going to dig.

Comment: If you like, you can provide the errors and I will try to help.

Comment: Ok, I have manage to solve error : to use `git submodule update --remote --merge`, specified a tracking branch is needed (by defaut it is master). It can be achieve with `git config -f .gitmodules submodule.submodulename.branch branchname`. Your command solve my problem, many thanks

Comment: GREAT NEWS! If I understand, it was a detached HEAD error... Alternatively, you could do that by navigating into the submodule folder and performing checkout not in a detached HEAD mode.